# Determine all solution of $z^{n-1}+z^{n-2}+...+z+1=0$. Here $n$ is an integer greater than one. $(z\in \mathbb{C})$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

**Determine all solution of $z^{n-1}+z^{n-2}+...+z+1=0$. Here $n$ is an integer greater than one.$(z\in \mathbb{C})$**

I could multiply everything by $z-1$ and get to that $z^n-1=0$ and so the roots would be precisely the n-root roots of $1$? or could I use the root test together with the factor theorem and that would tell me that two possible roots are $1$ or $-1$? so $1$ can not be and the only possible one would be $-1$, would not it have to consider the case that $n$ is even or odd?

Answer (score 4):

Since you have multiplied by $(z-1)$ on both sides, all the $n$th roots of unity except $z=1$ will satisfy $z^{n-1}+z^{n-2} + \cdots + z + 1 = 0$. For example, $z^3 + z^2+z+1=0$ for $z=-1, \pm i$ but not for $z=1$.

Also, note that $-1$ is not the $n$th root of unity when $n$ is odd.